# Expanded form of $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k + a}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a linear combination of the following sum: $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k + a}$, 
$a$ being a real number.

Let's say I have:

$H(n) = \sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k + 2} + \sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k + 3} - 2 \sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k + 4} $

Here is my problem: the series $\sum _{k} \frac{1}{k + a}$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.

However, I know H(n) converges, but I cannot show why and what is the limit. Can I expand $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k + a}$ in a more specific expression in that purpose? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it diverges by comparison, the thing is I have a linear combination of three sums like this which converges...

Comment: But that is a totally different question right? Asking about your approach to a problem rather than the underlying problem is generally a bad idea and just leads to confusion (however including what you have tried is not though).

Comment: I just clarified my problem so that it gets clearer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ok that is more like it. One way to solve your problem is to note that $\frac{1}{k+2} + \frac{1}{k+3} - \frac{2}{k+4} = \frac{3k+8}{(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)} \sim \frac{3}{k^2}$ for large $k$. That is: combine the three series into one and do a comparison of the general term with a suitable convergent series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: write

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+a}=\sum_{k=a}^{n+a}\frac{1}{k}$$

Take out the terms that don't match in the sums so that both the limits of the sums match as well as the term you sum over (with the above, that is $\tfrac1k$). Then you have only loose terms left and you can subtract the sums, leading to something that converges.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note $\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k + a} = \sum_{k = a}^{n + a}{1 \over k} =
> \sum_{k = 1}^{n + a}{1 \over k} - \sum_{k = 1}^{a - 1}{1 \over k} =
> H_{n + a} - H_{a - 1}}$.

Then
\begin{align}
\mrm{H}\pars{n} & =
\pars{H_{n + 2} - H_{1}} +
\pars{H_{n + 3} - H_{2}} -
2\pars{H_{n + 4} - H_{3}}
\\[5mm] & =
H_{n + 2} + H_{n + 3} - 2H_{n + 4} - 1 - {3 \over 2} + 2\,{11 \over 6} =
{7 \over 6} + H_{n + 2} - H_{n + 3} - {2 \over n + 4}
\\[5mm] & =
{7 \over 6} - {1 \over n + 3} - {2 \over n + 4}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\, \bbx{7 \over 6}
\end{align}